# Using the same counter as defined in an amsthm environment

Tags: numbering

I use the amsthm package to define enviroments for lemmas, theorems, etc. They all share the same counter. Using `\newcommand` I defined a macro for computational problems (name, input, output). I want the problems to share the same counter as the one used for lemmas, theorems and so on. How do I refer to it?

At the moment I have this:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lem}[defn]{Lemma}

\newcounter{problemdef}
\def\problemdefcnt{\thechapter.\arabic{problemdef}}
\newcommand{\problemdef}[3]{
\vspace{10pt} \noindent \textbf{Problem \problemdefcnt} #1 \\
\begin{tabular}{l | l}
\textbf{Input} & #2 \\
\textbf{Output} & #3
\end{tabular}
}
```

So, how do I appropriately define problemdefcnt to get smth like

> Definition 1.1
>
> Lemma 1.2
>
> Problem 1.3

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Use the counter `defn` instead of defining a new one.

Comment: Alternatively, define the `problemdef` counter first, tying it to the `chapter` counter, and then define new theorem environments using `\newtheorem{defn}[problemdef]{Definition}`, `\newtheorem{lem}[problemdef]{Lemma}`, etc.

Comment: @CharlesStaats You should turn your comments into an answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The counter is named `defn`, so you can easily use it.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lem}[defn]{Lemma}

\newcommand{\problemdef}[3]{%
  \par\vspace{10pt}
  \noindent\refstepcounter{defn}\textbf{Problem \thedefn} #1\\*[1ex]
  \begin{tabular}{l | l}
  \textbf{Input} & #2 \\
  \textbf{Output} & #3
  \end{tabular}%
  \par
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\begin{defn}
A definition
\end{defn}

\begin{lem}
A lemma
\end{lem}

\problemdef{Whatever}{1}{10}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that may do what you want. (Note that the vertical spacing, in particular, is probably not ideal, but I lack the experience to make it better.)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newcounter{problemdef}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theproblemdef}{\thechapter.\arabic{problemdef}}

\newtheorem{defn}[problemdef]{Definition}
\newtheorem{lem}[problemdef]{Lemma}

\newcommand{\problemdef}[3]{
\par\bigskip\noindent\textbf{Problem \refstepcounter{problemdef}\theproblemdef} #1
\par\medskip\noindent%
\begin{tabular}{l | l}
\textbf{Input} & #2 \\
\textbf{Output} & #3
\end{tabular}
\bigskip\par
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Chapter}

\begin{defn}
A (possibly non-hangleflip) groodle is \emph{normal} if it satisfies the 
logos property for all $x > 17$.
\end{defn}
\begin{lem}
All normal groodles are hangleflip.
\end{lem}
\problemdef{Factorials}{an integer $n$}{$n!$}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\problemdef{Instantiation}{a name of a class}{an instance of that class}
\begin{defn}
A normal groodle is \emph{quasicoherent} if, locally, it admits a presentation (which 
need not be finitely generated).
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```